# How does home network hosting work?

Tags: networking, hosting

I have a router in home. 3 different computers are connected to that router. Each computer has its own Apache software and has been set up to publish a webpage.

Router has only 1 IP address to outside. Lets say it is 88.65.1.7. All computers have different IP addresses like 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3.

I want to use 3 different domain names.
www.a.com
www.b.com
www.c.com

If I ping to www.a.com, or www.b.com, or www.c.com, all domains go to same 88.65.1.7 IP address. Because all of them are behind of same router.

What I can't understand is that how the network system can understand to go 192.168.0.1 when I type www.a.com to browser, and 192.168.0.2 when I type www.b.com, blah?

Or maybe I am thinking some things wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to set up port forwarding from the router to one machine, the 'main' machine, in whose apache httpd.conf you use rewrite rules to redirect the traffic, as so, assuming that your a.com machine is your main machine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.b\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://192.168.0.2:80$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.2:80/
```

This would funnel traffic for b.com *through* the machine for a.com.

Comment: Is this the only way? I mean what if I had set up mail server onto those computers, what would I do? How can redirecting work then? http.conf is only about Apache, right?

Comment: Yes, I specifically answered about Apache because that's what you had mentioned in your initial question.  I have never done SMTP redirection, however, so I can't give you a known working answer for that one, but some quick googling turned up a lot of resources for "redirect SMTP".  Alternately, you could have a single machine handle all port 25 traffic for all three domains.